# Is there a way to make an action space from a context free grammar?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, agent, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I'm looking to build an agent that can use messages that conform to a context-free grammar as its actions and work in an environment using gymnasium. I see they have a [text space](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/spaces/fundamental/#gymnasium.spaces.Text), but that doesn't really capture the action space, as messages that don't conform to the grammar aren't valid actions. An intermediate step would be like if instead of a charset I could specify a token set, but that's still only halfway there. Has anyone done anything similar or know a way to do this?